# How to add a caption *above* a table with `knitr::kable`?

Tags: r, knitr

When I render a simple Rmarkdown document as `github_document`, the table caption appears below the table rather than above. It also lacks the "Table: " prefix. Is there any way to change this behavior? Xie Yihui [has made clear](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1189#issuecomment-205956778) that `kable`'s default caption position should be above the table and when I run the same command outside of the Rmarkdown file, the caption does indeed appear on top.

The command I am referring to is

```r
knitr::kable(mtcars, caption = "mtcars")
```

and my Rmarkdown document looks like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: github_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars, caption = "mtcars")
```
````

Specifying `format = "pipe"` or `format = "simple"` does not seem to help.

Comment: This has been posted and now answered in https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting to a markdown output format `knitr::kable()` will default to `format = "pipe"`. This is for pandoc's pipe tables. `format = "simple"` is for Pandoc's simple table.

Those two syntax are Pandoc's markdown syntax. Pandoc's supports caption to be provided (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-table_captions).

**knitr** will write that for you: the table and caption in expected format.

However, output is defined to Github Flavored Markdown, so Pandoc's `gfm`. This flavor of Markdown does not support caption. Hence Pandoc will convert the pipe table in another Markdown table and suppressing the caption syntax to place the text below the table. This is Pandoc doing.

Take this `.md` file

```
Table: Demonstration of pipe table syntax.

| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |
```

doing a pandoc conversion will lead to

```
❯ pandoc -t gfm test.md
| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|    12 | 12   | 12      |   12   |
|   123 | 123  | 123     |  123   |
|     1 | 1    | 1       |   1    |

Demonstration of pipe table syntax.
```

Pandoc is placing the caption below when output is `gfm`

---

Question also asked in https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2074